# Twitter Bootstrap 2.2.2 row horizontal alignments and widths mixed 940px and 960px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a very basic layout done with Twitter Bootstrap:

```
<body>
<div class="container">

    <!-- Navbar -->
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Carousel -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" >
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- the content -->
    <section id="first_sect">
        <div class="row  alpha07">
            <div class="span12">
                <h1>header</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- whitespace row -->
    <div class="row  alpha07">
        <div class="span12">
            &nbsp; 
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- adress footer -->
    <section id="adress section">
        <div class="row  alpha07">...
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End of Bootstrap Container -->
</div>
</body>
```

And i have a row horizontal alignment and width problem, picture tells this better:
[image]

- Red background goes too much to left
- No padding to the right

Bootstrap is out-of-box no changes made.
Page code: http://jsfiddle.net/thomson256/DMnhL/10/
Twitter bootstrap version 2.2.2

**Question is:** is this somekind of bug or am i just missing some wrapping html elements or changes to .less variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as expected as far as I can see. Add an inner wrapping div for the content area and apply your css to that.

```
.inner {
  padding: 2em;
  background: rgba(150, 50, 50, 0.7);
}
```

Here is a fork: http://jsfiddle.net/gyf6c/1/.

Comment: For now i think i will do as in your fork, will do the trick, thank you. For the address footer a slightly more [verbose](http://pastebin.com/582VqQYG) code was needed.
Application in mind is to have a fullscreen image background therefore background color, so the conclusion might be that TwBS isn't planned for this? What is the mean of 960px and 20px margin on the left anyways? Just to margin possible left navi?

Comment: I think the margins have to do with the grid system.